# converting sql results to json php

Tags: php, json, postgresql, pdo

I am trying to convert results from a postgresql database to json. This is from an example I found online but it is giving me unexpected results.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=MYIP;dbname=MYDB;user=MYUSER;password=MYPASS");

$stmt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM message_log");
$json=json_encode($stmt);

echo $json;
?>
```

When I run the script, the result is this

> {"queryString":"SELECT * FROM message_log"}

Any idea what I am doing wrong here and what I can do to successfully convert pgsql results to json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$stmt` is not a result. It is a PDO Statement. You need to fetch the result.

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$stmt->execute();
$json = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll());
echo $json;
```